# How to make grid view item screen width Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to create a grid view where each item is in the center of the screen and width fits to given screen ? Whatever I do, in horizontal scroll my items are big and I can't scale them to the center of the screen. I want to scroll one item per screen.
I was trying ListView, Padding, Wrap, Align all the time the same.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

My code:

```dart
class NewestView extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewestView({Key? key, required this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final TestState state;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return BlocBuilder<NavigationCubit, NavigationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      return Builder(builder: (context) {
        return  GridView.count(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
          crossAxisCount: 1,
          children: _generateGrid(15, context),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
        );
      });
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _generateGrid(int number, BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> gridResult = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      IconData genIcon = RandomIconData.randomIcon();
      Image image = Image(image: Picsum().randomPic().image);
      gridResult.add(
        Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            onTap: () {
              _onTapAction(context, genIcon, image);
            },
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1
                    child: Center(
                      // color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                      child: Text(
                        'Test',
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .caption
                            ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: image,
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.monetization_on,
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return gridResult;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to make a ListView. But you went with GridView with crossAxisCount = 1. GridView children have aspect ratio of 1:1 unless you say otherwise. So change the GridView to ListView. Give the Card a child with size relative to viewport using MediaQuery so it doesn't get squeezed look.

[image: screenshot]

```js
class NewestView extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewestView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // final TestState state;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView(
      children: _generateGrid(15, context),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _generateGrid(int number, BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> gridResult = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      IconData genIcon = Icons.ac_unit_outlined;
      Image image = Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/450x800.png');
      gridResult.add(
        Card(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Center(
                    // color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    child: Text(
                      'Test',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .caption
                          ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: image,
                    );
                  }),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.monetization_on,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return gridResult;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about InkWell and onTap event ? I have to use gestures ?